# Values of x that satisfy this inequality

Tags: inequality

$||x-2|-3|>1$. I have made some cases but still the complete values don't come,plus I don't have any idea of how to sketch the graph for the lefy hand side of the inequality.

Comment: Please show the cases that you have made so we can see your work.

Comment: Okay thanks for the response. Is there any way I can take a pic from my phone of the work I've done and upload it here?

Comment: At the top, next to the B and the I, there should be a picture of a mountain. Click it and it will allow you to upload an image from your computer. If this does not work, upload the image to https://imgur.com/ and then put the link to the image inside of your question.

Comment: Also, if you only have equations in your work and no graphs/pictures, I suggest using MathJax to put in the equation. There is [a tutorial on MathJax at this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the response again and sorry but I'm on the mobile site and I have no options like I, B or anything no options. All I have is title space body space and tags space.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to leave now, but if you haven't already, try uploading it to https://imgur.com/ and then pasting the link into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no graphical method provided above, here I outline how to solve the solutions graphically.

The main technique to draw a graph involving absolute value, is to "**flip**" the part of curve below  x-axis **upwards**. For instance, in this question, consider $y=x-2$. For $x<2$, $y<0$. So for the graph $y=|x-2|$, flip the $x<2$ part upwards and we obtain ($1$):

[image]

For the "$-3$" part, shift the whole $y=|x-2|$ graph downward for $3$ units.

Repeat step (1) to construct $y=||x-2|-3|$.

Draw a line $y=1$. The required domain should be the parts of curve above the line.

Comment: great! "For the "−3" part, shift the whole y=|x−2| graph downward for 3 units" so by downwards do you mean 3 units in the -ve y axis?

Comment: Yes. Move the graph downwards along the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the graphical approach. That is what I was precisely looking for

Answer (score 3):

$$\left| \left| x-2 \right| -3 \right| > 1$$ is the same as $$ \left| x-2 \right|  < 2 \text{  or } \left| x-2 \right| >4$$ which further reduces to $$0<x<4 \text{  or } x<-2 \text{  or } x>6$$
I think this will be enough to sketch the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $||x-2|-3|>1$ has as an implication:

$$   |x-2|-3>1\text{ or }|x-2|-3<-1 \implies |x-2|>4\text{ or }|x-2|<2$$

This in turn implies:

$$ x-2>4\text{ or }x-2<-4\text{ or }-2<x-2<2 \implies x>6\text{ or }x<-2\text{ or }0<x<4$$

This means that $x \in (-\infty, -2)\cup(0,4)\cup(6,\infty)$.